# JSON.stringify is not working fine gives an extra "" to the key of a json

Tags: javascript, graphql

When I do JSON.stringify of an array using

```
let query = '{"query":"mutation {\\n  insert_'+table_name +'(objects: '+ 
JSON.stringify(objects)+', on_conflict: {action: update, constraint: '+table_name +
'_h_id_key, update_columns: '+update_columns+
'}) {\\n    affected_rows\\n  }\\n}\\n","variables":null}';
```

it gives me this

```
{"query":"mutation {\n  insert_users(objects: [{"h_id":"118208723166374240159","career_id":"118208723166374240159","name":"Joey Dash","email":"joydassudipta@gmail.com","role":"user","image_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hjMQ9VBKHIw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFDk/ePiRR90JHaM/s96-c/photo.jpg"}], on_conflict: {action: update, constraint: users_h_id_key, update_columns: [name,email,role]}) {\n    affected_rows\n  }\n}\n","variables":null}
```

notice each key is getting a "" which i don't want
I want something like this

```
{"query":"mutation {\n  insert_users(objects: [{h_id: \"esda\", career_id: \"esda\", name: \"joey\", email: \"joey@joey.com\", role: \"user\", image_url: \"kajids.png\"}], on_conflict: {action: update, constraint: users_h_id_key, update_columns: [name, email, image_url]}) {\n    affected_rows\n  }\n}\n","variables":null}
```

I want it like this because I am using graphql and it gives me lot of error

Is there anyway to make it like this

Comment: You're not escaping the `"`s correctly. `'{\"query\": \"mutation.......`

Comment: Never create json manually. As you are experiencing it is more work than it should be and far more error prone

Answer (score 1):

Its a good start that you have, but since you are already formatting JSON into which you are adding JSON.stringify(objects), it's not properly formatted for that placement. Instead you want to build your own string and concat it (like you are doing with table name).

`(objects: ['+ objects.map(function(object){ var str = '{'; /* iterate over key, value of object, adding it to string */ return str + '}';}).join(',') +']`